# office365 onedrive to use with assets

Tags: plugin-development

A little question , does anybody have or know someone with a plugin for Craft which can show Offie365 files/docs in Craft to use on an intranet/site?
Just like the feature below:

Assets are files managed by Craft. They live in “asset sources”, which represent physical folders on your server. And with Craft Pro, you can also set up Asset Sources that live on Amazon S3, Rackspace Cloud, and Google Cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be possible in Craft 3, when the concept of "Assets" will get converted into "Volumes". Unlike Craft 2, it will be possible to create a custom Volume with a plugin.

Be aware though, everything you're describing will require a custom plugin. At this point, no such plugin exists.